# Programmatic click on JS Notification

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing

I'm trying to test my webapp where I show a js Notification:
`new Notification("Title")`. Then I need to test if certain behaviour happens when I click on it. How can I simulate a user click on the notification in javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store notification object you get after the construction.Then you can do anything

```
  var notification = new Notification('test', {
    icon: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
    body: 'this is body of the notification'
  });                                  

  notification.onclick = function() { alert('got clicked'); }  //handler   

  var event = new Event('click');        //event creation 
  notification.dispatchEvent(event);     //triggering
```